# Firebase Database Listeners blocked by apparently non-blocking loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have a set of asynchronous Firebase listeners which listen to my db, and update local variables as changes to their remote counterparts are witnessed.

The listeners are attached on startup, and work fine independently. The callbacks fire whenever an update is witnessed.

However, I'm trying to write a loop which runs indefinitely (after all the listeners are attached etc) and performs operations each cycle using the variables which are maintained by the Firebase listeners.

I learnt from my initial attempt (a basic while loop) that node is single threaded, and hence a normal while loop is blocking, and prevents Node's event loop from firing.
I had a look round for some non-blocking alternatives and found:

```
self.processingLoop = function()
{
   //do stuff

   process.nextTick(self.processingLoop);
}
```

This should apparently implement a loop, whilst also not blocking the node Event Loop (and hence not blocking the Firebase listeners?), as the loop function is put in a callback queue to eventually be executed, as well as all other callbacks (which I am assuming encompases the firebase event callbacks).
The loop works fine, however my Firebase callbacks are still not being fired on updates to the db.

Here's an example of a callback which is no longer firing whilst the loop is running:

```
 self.attachMovementKeyListenerToCharacter = function(characterRefName, character, movingCharacters)
    {
        console.log("CharacterDao: Attaching MovementKeyListener to character: " + characterRefName);
        var characterMovementKeyStateRef = self.charactersRef.child(characterRefName + "/state/keyState/movementKeyState");

        //When a movementKey event fires, add or remove the player from the movingCharactersList
        characterMovementKeyStateRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot)
        {
            var keyThatWasPressed = snapshot.key;
            var newKeyValue = snapshot.val().value;
            var timestamp = snapshot.val().lastUpdated;

            console.log("Key event: " + keyThatWasPressed + " detected for character: " + characterRefName);

            //DO STUFF...
```

Does anyone know why my Firebase listeners are still blocked (I assume?) using this approach?
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have some firebase code to show for evaluation?

Comment: @deezy I've attached an example of a Firebase listener which is being blocked by the loop. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing

```
process.nextTick(self.processingLoop);
```

with

```
setTimeout(self.processingLoop, 0);
```

I read that process.nextTick was simply an optimized version of setTimeout, but they seem to both exhibit differing behaviours (process.nextTick is blocking to Firebase listeners, whereas setTimeout is not).

This is no longer urgent, but does anyone have any theories as to why this is the case?